# string::find Issue (C++)

Tags: c++, string, find

I've got a little issue with my string::find implementation.

The input is a long string, which consist of this possible example: input = "one_thousand_and_fifty_one".

My issue seems to be, that in an input string that contains more than one 'and', only the first and is removed, and the others aren't.

This is my code so far, which finds "and", but only removes is when the letter before 'a' isn't 's' (which indicates "thousand").

```
string toKill = "and";

size_t andF = input.find(toKill);
    if (andF != string::npos) {
        if (input[(andF - 1)] != 's') {
            input.erase(andF, 4);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention, that the only other word in the input that contains 'and' is 'thousand', so this IS a special case.

Comment: So what shall you do with husband, or band, or grand, or android? Perhaps you may want to check for a non-alpha before rather than just 's'? Perhaps you may want to check after the word as well.

Comment: Well for "android" it will crash, since it will access outside the string bounds: `input[-1]`.

Comment: @Michael, I know what it _will_ do, I was actually more asking what the poster _wanted_ to do :-)

Comment: Trust me, the only other word in the input that contains 'and' is thousand.

Comment: @Andrew, I'd still say it's better learning and for the future if it's failproof (to a reasonable level) now.

Comment: Okay, Andrew, on to the next step. All questions should have the code, expected results and actual results. What exactly is the issue you have (what are you seeing that's wrong)?

Comment: Alright, the issue I seem to have, is an input string that contains more than one and, the code only removes the first and.

Comment: @Andrew: You need a while loop and keep searching for the string, from the current position minus the length of the search string if your have deleted the search string.

Comment: What sort of conditions does the while loop need? EoF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string toKill = "and";
size_t andF = 0;

while ((andF = input.find(toKill, andF)) != string::npos) {
    if (andF == 0 || input[andF - 1] != 's') {
        input.erase(andF, 4);
    }
    else ++andF;
}
```

Comment: I'd remove the hardcoding of the 4, just to make it more general.

Comment: Looks like I forgot the need for a while loop.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I would too, but I based on his code, I wanted it to be clear what was missing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a regex for this (from boost, PCRE or the C++11 standard) - but if I had to do it myself, my code would look kind of like this:

```
string toKill = "and";
size_t pos = 0;
while( ( pos = s.find(toKill, pos) )!=std::string::n_pos )
{
  //Check it doesn't start with an additional letter
  if( pos!=0 && is_alpha(s[pos-1]) ) { pos++; continue; }
  //Check it doesn't end with an additional letter
  if( pos+toKill.size()!=s.size() && is_alpha(s[pos+toKill.size()]) { pos++; continue;}
  //Remove it and the trailing whitespace (or punctuation)
  s.erase(pos,toKill.size()+1);
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop if the string contains thousand.

Comment: You will need to search from `pos` if you don't call `erase()` otherwise you get an infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

You need (at least) two other things in your code. The first is a loop to process the entire string for `and` strings and the second is the ability to skip ones already checked.

You may also want to handle the possibility that the string *may* start with `and`, despite that being unlikely: be liberal with what you expect and specific with what you deliver.

The following code would be a good starting point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {
    std::string inputStr = "one thousand and fifty one";
    std::string killStr = "and ";

    size_t startPos = 0;
    size_t andPos;
    while ((andPos = inputStr.find (killStr, startPos)) != std::string::npos) {
        if ((andPos == 0) || (inputStr[(andPos - 1)] != 's')) {
            inputStr.erase(andPos, killStr.length());
            startPos = andPos;
        } else {
            startPos = andPos + 1;
        }
    }

    std::cout << inputStr << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

And, since I was being paranoid about having `and` at the start of the string, and Michael rightly called me on not handling it at the *end* of the string <sup>(a)</sup>, you can modify it do do so with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

static bool endsWith (std::string s1, std::string s2) {
    size_t s1Len = s1.length();
    size_t s2Len = s2.length();
    if (s2Len > s1Len)
        return false;
    return (strcmp (s1.c_str() + s1Len - s2Len, s2.c_str()) == 0);
}

int main (void) {
    std::string inputStr = "and one thousand and fifty one thousand and";
    std::string killStr = "and ";

    size_t startPos = 0;
    size_t andPos;
    while ((andPos = inputStr.find (killStr, startPos)) != std::string::npos) {
        if ((andPos == 0) || (inputStr[(andPos - 1)] != 's')) {
            inputStr.erase (andPos, killStr.length());
            startPos = andPos;
        } else {
            startPos = andPos + 1;
        }
    }
    if (!endsWith (inputStr, "sand") && endsWith (inputStr, "and"))
        inputStr.erase (inputStr.length() - 3);

    std::cout << inputStr << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If I'm going to be a pedant, I'd better well do it properly :-)

Comment: I like the addition of the space to the toKill string - it fixes the trailing character issue. However it wont catch a trailing "and" - like `"one hundred and"` but I'm assuming thats OK for the OPs case.